# Would questions on Anime Merchandise Care/Maintenance/Self-Repair be on-topic?

Tags: discussion, questions

One thing about our fandom, as with any entertainment fandom, is that we get to collect figures, posters, wall scrolls, books, cups, plushies, pantsu<sup>1</sup>, and like any fandom it can be pretty expensive.

After sinking hundreds of dollars/rubles/caps into those 2 matching figma of Madoka Kami and Akuma Homura you'd want to have them outside their box so you can pose them in a loving embrace of one another, but at the same time you'd want to keep them well maintained or when the worst happens, be able to repair them.

since we already have [merchandise](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/merchandise) would questions on Anime Merchandise Care/Maintenance/Self-Repair be on-topic? if not can we make them on-topic? if we can what guidelines should we set for questions and answers?

example questions:

> How to i restore color to my [C.C Wall Scroll?](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Fabric-Wall-Scroll-Poster-Inches/dp/B00502DNQ6)

> How can i wash a [Gift Nendoroid Plus Plushie?](http://www.goodsmile.info/en/product/3651/Nendoroid+Plus+Plushie+Series+44+Index.html)

> How can i repair the joint in a [Figma Figure?](http://www.goodsmile.info/en/product/5386/figma+Fubuki+Animation+ver.html)

---

<sup>1: i swear i've seen pantsu advertised in a JList email</sup>

Comment: I think it would involve more knowledge on DIY stuffs rather than knowledge on anime and manga. I am also not quite sure whether people on our site has expertise in this topic or not. If you really has the problem yourself, and the rest agrees with a trial run, then we can put up such questions and see whether it would work out.

Comment: I agree with @nhahtdh that is a separate area of expertise. The same information could be applied to a generic plushie or a non-anime wall scroll.